# Getting/updating YouTube favorites using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, youtube-api, asihttprequest

I am trying to work with youtube apis. I have 2 methos to get favorite list and add a specified video to that list. Both methods not work. I received the error as below: `HTTP/1.1 401 Unknown authorization header` error.
Here is my codes:

```
#define CONNECTION_YOUTUBE                  @"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/"
#define CONNECTION_ADD_FAVORITE_VIDEO @"users/default/favorites"
#define CONNECTION_GET_FAVORITE_LIST @"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/favorites"

- (void) getFavoriteList{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:CONNECTION_GET_FAVORITE_LIST];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:[@" Bearer "  stringByAppendingString:[appDelegate userInfo].accessTokenYoutube ]];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"X-GData-Key" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"key=%@",YOUTUBE_DEVELOPER_KEY]];

    [request startAsynchronous];
    [request setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSString* respondMessage = [request responseStatusMessage];
        NSLog(@"Respond compelet with message: %@",respondMessage);
    }];
    [request setFailedBlock:^{
        NSString* respondMessage = [request responseStatusMessage];
        NSLog(@"Respond failed with message: %@",respondMessage);
    }];
    [request release];
}
- (void) addToFavoriteTheVideoWithID:(NSString *)strVideoID{

    //prepare url
    NSString *rawUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", CONNECTION_YOUTUBE, CONNECTION_ADD_FAVORITE_VIDEO    ];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL URLWithString:rawUrl] autorelease];

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];

    //prepare form body
    NSString *rawXML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <entry xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\"><yt:videoid>xxxx%@</yt:videoid></entry>",strVideoID];
    NSMutableData *soapData = [[[NSMutableData alloc]initWithData:[rawXML dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ]]autorelease] ;
    [request setPostBody:soapData];

    //prepare request header
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"SOAPAction" value:@""];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/atom+xml"];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Length" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",soapData.length]];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:[@" Bearer "  stringByAppendingString:[appDelegate userInfo].accessTokenYoutube ]];
   // NSString* token = [@" Bearer "  stringByAppendingString:[appDelegate userInfo].accessTokenYoutube ];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"GData-Version" value:@"2"];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"X-GData-Key" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"key=%@",YOUTUBE_DEVELOPER_KEY]];

    [request startAsynchronous];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(didAddVideoToFavoriteFinish: )];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(didAddVideoToFavoriteFail:)];

}
```

Please helps.
Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than constructing your requests by hand (and opening yourself up to a variety of different potential problems), I'd strongly suggest that you using the [GData Objective-C client library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/) (if you want to use [v2 of the YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_audience)) or the [Google APIs Objective-C client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/) (if you want to use the newer [v3 of the YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/)).

Either of those libraries will simplify the authorization and request process for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jeff. I just want to constructing the requests by hand because of special requirements in my project. Could you give me an example to get data from youtube's raw API within accesstoken?

Comment: The `Authorization` header format is documented at https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Calling_a_Google_API Taking a look at your code, maybe the problem is that you have a space before the string "Bearer"?